# secure login script from wikihow

Tags: php, mysql

Has anybody used this [script](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) from wikihow?

By default both the login in and registering pages redirect you to "protected_page.php" the protected page is supposed to validate your login with: `

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Protected Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
        <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
            <p>
```

or

```
<?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that I always get the error msg, even though my db is configured and the registration info is sent to the db, Ive even edited the reg form to add more info without any problem on the DB side, but still I always get this error msg when trying to log in on the site. Anybody had this problem?

Comment: Please, could you tell us what error message are you getting?

Comment: "You are not authorized to access this page"

Comment: And are you sure the name and password are corect? Try print `$_SESSION` below the HTML. Like this: `<pre><?php print_R($_SESSION);?></pre>`. Also do the same for POST to see if the login details are being sent.

Comment: I get "Array
(
)" if I do add the print session, the login and pass are correct, and the "process_login.php" wont send me to the above page unless it gets "if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header("Location: ../protected_page.php");"

Comment: Try to put random `echo` and `print_R` around the code until you know how it works. I will be here to explain anything - but I'm not a PHP debugger console. Btw.: You can wrap code in \` to make it gray here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and found the solution.  My issue was in my php.ini file.

I had to change

`session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"`

to:

`session.save_path = "THE_DOCUMENT_ROOT_FOLDER_FROM_MY_HOST"`.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer but I do know that the problem must be found in the sec_session_start function:
If you don't use `$session_name = 'sec_session_id'`,
 `session_name($session_name);`
and `session_regenerate_id(true);`
the code works.

```
function sec_session_start() {

//  $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name

    /*Sets the session name.
     *This must come before session_set_cookie_params due to an undocumented bug/feature in PHP.
     */

//  session_name($session_name);

    $secure = true;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
            $cookieParams["path"],
            $cookieParams["domain"],
            $secure,
            $httponly);

    session_start();            // Start the PHP session
//  session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.

}
```